# Condition on basis of flux size

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a scenario where i want to have checks on basis of flux size e.g  if flux is empty then call function A else if flux size is 1 do call function B  else callfunctionC

Currently i am using below code to solve my problem

```
Flux<Category> categories = getCategories();

List<Category> list = categories.collectList().block();

if(list.empty())
   functionA();
else if (list.size() == 1)
   functionB();
else
  functionC();
```

I want to know how to solve this by without block

Comment: You'll always need to use something like `categories.collectList()` since a `Flux` has no concept of a size until it's complete (of course, it may also never complete.) You can of course avoid the block by just calling `flatMap()` on the `Mono<List>` and then performing whatever function you like depending on the list's size, but not sure that's what you're after?

Comment: You are looking on a flux as if it was a list of "objects" which it isn't. There is no "state" in a flux. A flux i more like something you listen to. Its like schroedingers cat, you have no idea whats in it, until you subscribe to it. So what you are asking for is not possible unless you use a Mono<List<Category>> and then flatmap on it.